# mysql table trigger throughs error

Tags: mysql, triggers

Getting error on following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER limit_refferals AFTER INSERT
 ON wpmr_aff_referrals
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 DECLARE vCNT INT;
 DECLARE USERID varchar(50);
 DECLARE AFFILIATEID varchar(50);
DECLARE i INTEGER;
     DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT USER_ID,affiliate_id
 FROM `wpmr_aff_referrals` WHERE affiliate_id=:NEW.affiliate_id;
 SELECT CUSTOMERLEVEL(:NEW.affiliate_id) INTO vCNT;
    IF (vCNT>=3)
 set i=1;
OPEN curs1;
 read_loop: LOOP
FETCH curs1 INTO USERID,AFFILIATEID;
 SELECT CUSTOMERLEVEL(:NEW.affiliate_id) INTO vCNT;
IF (vCNT>=3)
set i=i+1;
ELSE
set new.affiliate_id= AFFILIATEID;
END IF;
END LOOP read_loop;
CLOSE curs1;

 END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ':NEW.affiliate_id; SELECT CUSTOMERLEVEL(:NEW.affiliate_id) INTO
>   vCNT;
>       IF (vC' at line 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER limit_refferals BEFORE INSERT
ON wpmr_aff_referrals
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE vCNT INT;
    DECLARE USERID varchar(50);
    DECLARE AFFILIATEID varchar(50);
    DECLARE i INTEGER;
    DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT USER_ID,affiliate_id
                FROM `wpmr_aff_referrals` WHERE affiliate_id=NEW.affiliate_id;

    SELECT CUSTOMERLEVEL(NEW.affiliate_id) INTO vCNT;
    IF (vCNT >=3) THEN    /*<------------Made changes at this line*/
        set i=1;

        OPEN curs1;
            read_loop : LOOP
            FETCH curs1 INTO USERID,AFFILIATEID;
                SELECT CUSTOMERLEVEL(NEW.affiliate_id) INTO vCNT;
                IF (vCNT>=3) THEN        /*<------------Made changes at this line*/
                    set i=i+1;
                ELSE
                    set new.affiliate_id= AFFILIATEID;
                END IF;
            END LOOP read_loop;
        CLOSE curs1;

    END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Try above code.

One more thing you can't use `NEW` `row` for `BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER`.So i had made changes to `AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER`.
We don't need **`:`** for `NEW` and `OLD` value,you can directly check that value using `NEW.VAL` and `OLD.VAL`.
Also whenever you use `IF` IN **`TRIGGER`**,**`PROCEDURE`** and **`FUNCTION`** put THEN and then write you logic

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Muhammad Muazzam You can Upvote also,if it's resolved your issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ":" to pass the parameter NEW.affiliate_id to the CUSTOMERLEVEL function like this:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERLEVEL(NEW.affiliate_id) INTO vCNT
```